# How to write a query in sql which does "=COUNTIF(B2:B4,">"&B2)" of excel/sheets?

Tags: sql, excel, google-sheets

I am trying to do "=COUNTIF(B1:B3,">"&B1)" in sql, it counts the number of elements in a column, from B1 row to B3, which are greater then B1. We are doing this for every 3 rows.

Suppose we have B column

532.02

667.96

588.1

579.35

623.98

621.29

Now we i need to calculate the number of elements which are greater then elements B(i) for every three rows.

532.02 -> 2 (=COUNTIF(B1:B3,">"&B1) (Number of elements from B1 to B3 which are greater then B1)

667.96 -> 0 (=COUNTIF(B2:B3,">"&B2) (Number of elements from B2 to B3 which are greater then B2)

588.1 -> 0 (=COUNTIF(B3:B3,">"&B3)(Number of elements from B3 to B3 which are greater then B3)

579.35 -> 2 (=COUNTIF(B4:B6,">"&B4) (Number of elements from B4 to B6 which are greater then B4)

623.98 -> 0 (=COUNTIF(B5:B6,">"&B5) (Number of elements from B5 to B6 which are greater then B5)

621.29 -> 0 (=COUNTIF(B6:B6,">"&B6) (Number of elements from B6 to B6 which are greater then B6)

So in sheets/excel, we use this (=COUNTIF(B5:B6,">"&B5), but how write query in sql on the basis of this?

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? (Remove the other tags.)

Comment: Why do you tag "sql", "mysql" and "oracle"?

Answer (score 1):

You could of use the [`CELL` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071?hl=en) with a new column that has the intervals of `3` (*3,6,9,etc*).

Then, you can build the formula to get the value of the interval column and proceed with the formula you have.

So, the formula to build would be like:

> (=COUNTIF(B5:"B"&=CELL("contents", H33),">"&B5)

In this case, `H33` has the interval.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to have different behaviour depending on the position of the record (the groups of 3) then you have to have some way of showing that position, SQL data isn't guaranteed to be in a specific order unless you specify. You would likely need to add a unique ID for each line that increments.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
    ROW_N NUMBER,
    AMMOUNT NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (1, 532.02);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (2, 667.96);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (3, 588.1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (4, 579.35);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (5, 623.98);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (6, 621.29);
```

Then you can use a [modulo function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to change behaviour depending on whether the line you are working with has a reference that is exactly divisible by 3, a remainder of one, or a remainder of 2.

In order to compare values between different records on the same table you would likely need to use a self join. In this instance you are sometimes doing this twice, so you need 2 self joins.

The way I implemented it was to use a case statement, which is fine for doing a couple of comparisons, but isn't really scalable.

I used unions at the end just to get the data back into the original format.

```
WITH calcs AS 
(
    SELECT 
        a.row_n  AS rown_a,
        a.amount AS amount_a,
        0        AS gtr_a,
        b.row_n  AS rown_b,
        b.amount AS amount_b,
        CASE
            WHEN b.amount < a.amount THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS gtr_b,
        c.row_n AS rown_c,
        c.amount AS amount_c,
        CASE
            WHEN c.amount > a.amount
                 AND c.amount < b.amount THEN 1
            WHEN c.amount < a.amount
                 AND c.amount > b.amount THEN 1
            WHEN c.amount < a.amount
                 AND c.amount < b.amount THEN 2
            ELSE 0
        END AS gtr_c
    FROM   
        my_table a,
        my_table b,
        my_table c
    WHERE  
        MOD(a.row_n, 3) = 0
        AND b.row_n = a.row_n - 1
        AND c.row_n = a.row_n - 2
)
SELECT *
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         rown_a, amount_a, gtr_a
     FROM calcs
     UNION
     SELECT 
         rown_b, amount_b, gtr_b
     FROM calcs
     UNION
     SELECT 
         rown_c, amount_c, gtr_c
     FROM calcs) x
ORDER BY 1
```

This query is a bit of a mess, but what you are trying to do in SQL is a bit weird IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add something. Maybe this query can add some value to you, as to do operations with the following rows without the use of joins.

```
SELECT
    ROW#,
    B_column first#,
    SUM(B_column) OVER (order by ROW# rows between 1 following and 1 following) second#,
    SUM(B_column) OVER (order by ROW# rows between 2 following and 2 following) third#
FROM (  
    SELECT 
        row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) ROW#,
        B_column
    FROM [your_schema].[your_table]
) A
```

Thank you